# "php artisan <anything>" doesn't produce any output at all(!!)

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan

I've got a directory in which a Laravel website is currently *running.*  (I think it's Laravel 5.2, Windows 10.)  So, while `cd`'d into the website directory, I type in: **`php artisan`** ...

... and *nothing* happens.  No output of any kind.  **`php artisan *anything-at-all*`** likewise produces no output.  And, no commands actually do anything.

With no output, how in the heck can I *debug* this?

Comment: Is nothing written to the logs?

Comment: *Where* would I find logs for a command entered on the command-line?  That's what I'm looking for, indeed.

Comment: in `storage/logs` within the codebase

Comment: Well, there are `.json` files in that directory, but none for today's date, and they all appear to be output from the website that runs here.  (The directory is actually `storage/logs/CustomLogger` ...)

Comment: Could there be anything in the PHP logs for the server?

Comment: I think that those files *are* output from when the website is running under the server.  In my case, I'm using the command-line shell, cd'd into the directory in question, and trying to directly run the `artisan` command.  And I'm getting zero output on the command-line ... no "list of commands," either ... and `storage/logs` doesn't appear to have anything either.  I don't expect "output from the server" since the server's off doing its thing and here I am on the command-line.

Comment: I feel like I should "start PHP in some debugging mode ..."  Some "verbose" something-or-other ... something to make PHP chatty.  If this were Perl, I could just `perl -d`, but I gather that PHP's a bit more complicated.

Comment: What happens if you change the error reporting level of artisan.php and then try to run something?

Comment: How do I do that, Joshua?  (Note that I am `ssh`ing into this session on a remote machine.)

Comment: It depends on which server you are using

Comment: Well, thanks for the assistance but I'll wind up this chat now and see what else I can do to solve this.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

While I never did figure out what was causing the problem, I *did* discover that `composer install` (not `update`) miraculously made the problem go away.

I *also* was able to hammer-on the `artisan` command (only in PHP-7) to cause it to actually spit out an exception:  `class "log" does not exist.`  I coaxed out a traceback and from this discovered that `kernel` had gotten a "ThrowableError," although the traceback didn't tell me what it was.

**Wild Guess:** What I surmise to be happening here is that Laravel has captured all of the exception output for itself, intending to log it.  When it couldn't do so, it simply ... quit, producing no output at all.  I think that this is probably the explanation for other such cases which have from time-to-time been reported here.

Specifically, what I did to catch this *(and it only worked in PHP-7),* was to put a `try..catch` block around the actual command-call, printing the message and traceback-string from the `Exception` object.  This was the only way that I could discover that any exception had been thrown at all.

Comment: Thanks! Encountered this issue today with php 8.1.27 and laravel 10.4.1; no output in any logs, php artisan just exiting with no output. Running 'composer install' saved my bacon.